# Play audio in IE11. audio.play() isn't working

Tags: javascript, audio, internet-explorer-11

I know IE11 is a very special browser. I did not know, however that `audio.play()` doesn't work. Test in any modern browser and this simple snippet works. Test in IE11 and you hear silence. Is there a simple fix for this?

```js
function playAudio() {
  var audio = document.querySelector('audio[src*="media"');
  audio.play();
}

var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', playAudio);
```

```css
@import url( "https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css" );

body {
  line-height: 2rem;
}
.button-container {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 80px auto;
}
p {
  width: 200px;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button>Play Audio</button>
</div>

<p>
  Click this button in any other browser but IE11 &amp; below and it should work.<br>
  <b>:(</b>
</p>

<audio src=
  "http://vocaroo.com/media_command.php?media=s05tGWFyu2eb&command=download_wav"
>
</audio>
```

Comment: look at this [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility) - see how IE does **not** support PCM in WAVE format?

Comment: @JaromandaX Is the only option to include a different file format?

Comment: yes, the only option is to include a format that IE supports - MP3 seems to be the only universally supported audio format - oh, there's AAC in MP4, but that's a whole lot of messing around really